# Can we Change Maven default Directory(.m2) Name?

Tags: java, linux, windows, maven

As we know Maven Downloaded all Jars from repository to local machine in a default directory name **.m2** and location of this directory in **Windows** machine(Inside **User** Folder) Or in **Home** directory in case of **Linux** machine. Now my question is that can we change the name of **.m2** to **myjars** or some other name?

Comment: What would be the reason to name it as ".m2" by default ?

Comment: @Ram Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306372/how-did-the-m2-folder-in-maven-get-its-name

Comment: thanks mate for the link

Answer (score 25, accepted):

YES:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
   <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
   <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
   <offline>false</offline>
   ...
 </settings>
```

- **localRepository:** This value is the path of this build system's local repository. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository. This element is especially useful for a main build server allowing all logged-in users to build from a common local repository.
- **interactiveMode:** true if Maven should attempt to interact with the user for input, false if not. Defaults to true.
- **usePluginRegistry:** true if Maven should use the ${user.home}/.m2/plugin-registry.xml file to manage plugin versions, defaults to false. Note that for the current version of Maven 2.0, the plugin-registry.xml file should not be depended upon. Consider it dormant for now.
- **offline:** true if this build system should operate in offline mode, defaults to false. This element is useful for build servers which cannot connect to a remote repository, either because of network setup or security reasons.

Comment: Ok do you mean inside  <localRepository> tag we can give any valid path of machine?

Comment: I'm confused. I can use the settings file to change the location of the .m2 folder? But the settings file is in the .m2 folder. I was expecting to find an environment variable to set.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can do that. But make sure, you make the appropriate path change in the `<localRepository>` of your `settings.xml` present in the `conf` folder of maven home directory.